# how to make a sortable component that swap position instead of reorder in react-sortable-hoc

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I have a sortable list of 5 items, which i can drag and drop to reordenate, like the example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-sortable-hoc-test-q6jro

when I drag the "item 5" bellow "item 1", the other items are properly reordenate.
when you move one item up, the others go down to keep up the list.

But, instead of it, i want to swap positions of the items, 5 for 1, and 1 for 5, and the other items remains intact, and using this react-sortable-hoc component. 
I have no idea how to do it, its my first time with react.